# Массивы на Delphi

Tags: массивы, delphi

```
program Project4_2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
const M=1; N=10;
var d:array [M..N] of real;
I:byte;
begin
For i:=1 to 10 do
Readln (d[i]);

Правильно ли я написал операцию ввода вещественных чисел в одномерный массив? И еще один вопрос: Как мне написать так, чтобы идентификаторы именованных констант (M,N) использовались при вычислениях вместо значений границ индексов массива.
P.S. Хотелось бы узнать как найти минимальное и максимальное значение элементов массива =)
```

Comment: 1) Вроде правильно, возьми и проверь :)
2) Low(d) и High(d)

Comment: раз есть константы, то их и стоит использовать в цикле. То есть

    For i:=M to N do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод правильный, про константы ответили выше. Нахождение min и max:

```
 min:=d[M];
 max:=d[M];
 for i:=M to N do
 begin
  if d[i]<min then
    min:=d[i];
  if d[i]>max then
    max:=d[i];
 end;
```

Comment: Лучше не использовать имена методов (`min` и `max`, из стандартного модуля Math) для имен переменных.